# How to show a list of elements using a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have three tables, one of which is a many-to-many relationship table:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end
```

and the table Categorizations:

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I saved the categories ids in a array:

```
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name_product, :hallmark, :description, :image_url, :price, category_ids:[])
  end
```

In new.html.erb:

```
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
   <label>
      <%= check_box_tag "product[category_ids][]", category.id, field.object.categories.include?(Category) %>
      <%= category.name_category %>
   </label>
  <%end%>
```

I can't display the category names. In show.html.erb I tried everything, but it only displays the ID of the categories in which the product belongs.

How do I display the category names?  In the database I can do a `JOIN`, but in Ruby on Rails it is difficult.

Comment: What is sector? Your `new.html.erb` code has nothing to do with the rest of the information in the question.

Comment: "In the database I can do a JOIN...". Yes, and that's probably the right thing to do. You want to avoid moving a lot of data and having Ruby or Rails do the heavy lifting when the DBM is capable of doing the work of sifting and crunching. I've seen tasks that took multiple seconds for data movement and crunching in Ruby take sub-second times for the DBM to search, sift and crunch and then return only the records needed. That pays off in reduced network load and CPU load on the application or web server.

Answer (score 0):

It does not able in Rails to store a relation in an array column. You may load necessary `categories` and make access by `category id`.

```
# for single product
category_ids = product.category_ids
# for many products
category_ids = products.flat_map(&:category_ids)

# load categories
categories = Category.where(id: category_ids).index_by(&:id)
# the result structure 
# {1 => #<Category id: 1, ...>, 2 => #<Category id: 2, ...> ... }

# now all related categories preloaded
products.each do |product|
  product.category_ids.each do |category_id|
    puts categories[category_id]
  end
end
```